# How to wrap text around theorem box?

Tags: theorems, wrapfigure

I'm using the `thmtools` to create theorem boxes.

```
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[unq]{unique}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}

\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=6pt, spacebelow=6pt,
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
notefont=\mdseries, notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadspace=1em,
qed=
]{mystyle}

\declaretheorem[style=mystyle, numbered=yes,name=Definition of bla and bla, shaded={bgcolor=Lavender,textwidth=20em}]{defBDL}
```

How do I wrap text around that 20em-wide box?

Comment: Instead of code snippets, please provide a complete, [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sample (using the `lipsum` package to create the dummy text):

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[unq]{unique}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}

\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=6pt, spacebelow=6pt,
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
notefont=\mdseries, notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadspace=1em,
qed=
]{mystyle}

\declaretheorem[style=mystyle, numbered=yes,name=Definition of bla and bla, shaded={bgcolor=Lavender,textwidth=20em}]{defBDL}

\usepackage{lipsum} %To produce dummy text

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{20em}
  \begin{defBDL}
    \lipsum[10]
  \end{defBDL}
\end{wrapfigure} \lipsum[2-4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Solid example. Appreciated. Thank you, Andrew.